# How to fix the css padding

Tags: html, css, forms, css-float

I m struggling with this landing page since yesterday and I cant fix the form section.

Here's [a link](http://socialmedia.euc.ac.cy/landing/masterlaw//)! And as you can see the form at the end of the page is a mess.

Find bellow the CSS snippet that I used. what i m doing wrong?

```
#form {
background: #F1F1F1;
font-size: 22px;
margin:  25px 20px 35px 0px;
padding: 35px 5px 35px 0px;
text-align: left;
width: 100%;}
```

Comment: how should it look like? do you have a screenshot of the expected result or something?

Comment: Try to put form into DIV and then insert this style to the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i've changed the following attributes under `#form` and it worked:

```
#form {
 padding: 35px;
 width: auto;
 margin: 25px 0;
}

#form p {
  float: none; /*or remove float line */
}
```

Once you set a width and you add padding, it will be bigger than the setted widh. Did I explain myself? (my english sucks)

There'll be some padding under the submit button but that'll be easy for you to fix it.